# Is there a way to retrieve single row from database as key value only in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

can i retrieve single row from database like this in Laravel

```
["name"=>"jhon",
"age"=>"18"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `first()` method:

```
User::where('name', 'John Smith')->first();
```

Or the `find()` method:

```
User::find($id);
```

It will return an object. If you need an array, use the `toArray()` method to convert an object to an array:

```
User::find($id)->toArray();
```

Comment: it will return an object , how can i get it as an array , or should i create foreach ?

Comment: @wahdan no need for using `foreach`, because it's an object. Use the `toArray()` method to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Eloquent Collection methods to transform it however you want.

```
$people = User::where('name', 'John Smith')->get()->map(function ($person) {
    return [
        'id'   => $person->id,
        'name' => $person->name
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `first()` method along with `id` because `id` is unique key for every row

```
 User::whereId($id)->first();
```